# Tuning SQL query : subquery with aggregate function on the same table

Tags: sql, subquery, aggregate-functions, sybase, query-performance

The following query takes approximately 30 seconds to give results.
table1 contains ~20m lines
table2 contains ~10000 lines

I'm trying to find a way to improve performances. Any ideas ?

```
declare @PreviousMonthDate datetime 
select @PreviousMonthDate = (SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, '19000101', GETDATE()) - 1, '19000101') as [PreviousMonthDate])

     select  
 distinct(t1.code), t1.ent, t3.lib, t3.typ from table1 t1, table2 t3
     where (select min(t2.dat) from table1 t2 where   t2.code=t1.code) >@PreviousMonthDate
and t1.ent in ('XXX')
and t1.code=t3.cod
and t1.dat>@PreviousMonthDate
```

Thanks

Comment: which db you are using ??

Comment: Some sample data would be nice.  Right off the bat, if you could do away with those correlated subqueries, you'd probably be better off.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  thanks  .. i have not noted ..

Comment: @scaisEdge, I'm using sybase

Comment: `DISTINCT` is a part of `SELECT DISTINCT`, and applies to the whole selected rows. Skip those redundant parentheses, and write `select distinct t1.code, t1.ent, ...` to make things clearer.

Comment: Sybase ASE? Sybase ASA? Sybase IQ?

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen , I tried rewriting subquery by using an inner join with select .. group by query but performances are worse

Comment: @davidhale Yes, but what about indices?  Did you try tuning the join query?

Comment: using Sybase ASE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your query, more sensibly written:

```
 select t1.code, t1.ent, t2.lib, t2.typ
 from table1 t1 join
      table2 t2
      on t1.code = t2.cod
 where not exists (select 1
                   from table1 tt1
                   where tt1.code = t1.code and
                         tt1.dat <= @PreviousMonthDate 
                  ) and
       t1.ent = 'XXX' and 
       t1.dat > @PreviousMonthDate;
```

For this query, you want the following indexes:

- `table1(ent, dat, code)`  -- for the where
- `table1(code, dat)`       -- for the subquery
- `table2(cod, lib, typ)`   -- for the join

Notes:

- Table aliases should make sense.  `t3` for `table2` is cognitively dissonant, even though I know these are made up names.
- `not exists` (especially with the right indexes) should be faster than the aggregation subquery.
- The indexes will satisfy the `where` clause, reducing the data needed for filtering.
- `select distinct` is a statement.  `distinct` is not a function, so the parentheses do nothing.
- *Never* use comma in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, standard `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: any particular reason why table1 index have fields on inverted order?

Comment: Great !! Thanks. I just added distinct to the first select and it took 2.5 seconds

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza . . . I had the reasons reversed.  Do the indexes make more sense now?

Comment: Nope I mean why one have `dat,code` and the other `code,dat`